# How can I write an Excel query that counts unique text data while also excluding data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given the following data in Excel, how can I write a query to:

a) Show the number of unique (one time) logins only and
b) Exclude "admin" user logins in the count

The result should be 3.

The data:

admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
**jdoe**
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
**hsmith**
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
admin
**jdoe**
admin
admin
admin
admin
**jstewart**
admin
admin
admin
admin

Comment: I have tried this: =SUM(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(A2:A50)>0,MATCH(A2:A50,A2:A50,0),""), IF(LEN(A2:A50)>0,MATCH(A2:A50,A2:A50,0),""))>0,1))-1) ...this works and the -1 removes the "admin" user count.  I am looking for a better way to filter out the admin user however since I have some other exclusions/filters to consider in the formula.

Comment: Please edit your question and show what you have tried.

Comment: FYI other exclusions/filters I would add in later would be a date range, and to match against a "ACTIVITY_LOGIN_USER" activity type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you always have at least one admin in your column, then you can count all distinct values in the column and then subtract one. Assuming your data fall in the range `A1:A100`, then this formula will give the desired answer

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:A100,A1:A100&""))-1
```

If you are not sure about if there is admin, then you can use this formula

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:A100,A1:A100&"")) -IF(ISERROR(MATCH("admin",A1:A100,0)),0,1)
```

Comment: Nice.  In case there's no "admin," you could subtract `IFERROR(MATCH("admin",A1:A999,0)>0,0)` instead of `1`.